# Cast number to type?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

How do you go about casting numbers to specific data types?

    `Example:
    253 is 32-bit signed integer
    253L is 64-bit signed integer
    253D is Double precision float`

As you can see you can cast directly to Long and Double, but there are certain problems I have here. I cannot cast to byte, single, 16bit, unsigned...

It becomes a problem when I have to input data into many different functions with arguments of varying data types:

    `Method1( byte Value );
    Method2( sbyte Value );
    Method3( ushort Value );
    //Etc.`

Comment: Try `(Type)Variable`; for example `(byte)numvar` or `(double)124.2`

Comment: Did a call such as Method1(253) cause you any harm?

Comment: Casting via `(datatype)` doesn't work on values, wish it did... It did cause trouble, as C# recognizes all values as 32-bit integers by default.

Comment: "functions with arguments of varying data types" sounds like a situation calling for generics, to me.

Comment: So sorry, about this, but @AlphaDelta, you were right. I can cast via:
`Method( (type)numvar );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using int.Parse(string) or Convert.ToInt32 will do the trick.
Or you could try casting the value expicitly like that:

```
int age = 53;

Method1((byte) age);
```

Comment: Yeah it works like that. I didn't realize it at first because I made a mistake elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Convert` class:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(anything);
```

Comment: I thought of doing it myself, but it seemed like a pain to have to use the convert class for all of my values...